# Ember data with RESTless JSON Api like github?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to get JSON data of an api like github. Is this the right way?

Javascript:

```
var Github = window.Github = Ember.Application.create({
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

Github.Adapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
    find: function(store, type, id) {
        //var url = type.url;
        var url  = "https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js/commits";
        //url = url.fmt(id);

        jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            // data is a hash of key/value pairs. If your server returns a
            // root, simply do something like:
            // store.push(type, id, data.person)
            console.dir(data);
            store.push(type, id, data);
        });
    }
});

Github.Commit = DS.Model.extend({
    sha: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string')
});

Github.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'Github.Adapter'
});



Github.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Github.Store.find('commit');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.2.0/ember.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.3/ember-data.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iPiNUrun/4/edit)

But what is the problem? I don't understand how to interpret the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, it's working but im not sure if this is the right way :)

JavaScript

```
var Github = window.Github = Ember.Application.create({
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

Github.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
        payload.forEach(function(element, key){
            element.id = element[type.idField];
        });
        var newPayload = {};
        newPayload[Ember.String.pluralize(type.typeKey)] = payload;
        return this._super(store, type, newPayload, id, requestType);
    }
});

Github.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'repos/emberjs/ember.js',
    host: 'https://api.github.com'
});

Github.Commit = DS.Model.extend({
    sha: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string')
});
Github.Commit.idField = 'sha';

Github.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(){
        var store = this.get('store');
        store.find('commit');
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/iPiNUrun/10/edit